# Change the font proprietes of a piece of text

Tags: python, text, tkinter, fonts, notepad

I'm making a notepad and I've created tools for fonts, but this changes the font of all the text, not just the selected piece or the part where you are

The code for all the tools looks like this:

```
def ng():
    global fn #the font
    global b #Bold variable

    b=not b
    if b==True:
        fn.configure(weight="bold")
    if b==False:
        fn.configure(weight="normal")

    scroll.config(font=fn)
```

How I do this?

Comment: Have you done any research before askng? There are many questions on this site with examples.

Comment: Yes, I researched a lot before 0_0

Comment: You need to tag the slice of text you want to look different and then use the tag_config method to change the properties of text with the tag.  This is how, for instance, tkinter-based IDLE syntax colors python code.  Read the Text widget doc in `http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html`.  Also try searching SO `tkinter` tagged questions for 'Text tags' or something like that.

Comment: If you did research, include some of what you learned in your question. For example, things you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example, using foreground color instead of font because it is easier, and creating new fonts is a separate issue.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.tag_config('RED', foreground='red')
text.tag_config('BLUE', foreground='blue')
text.insert('insert', 'Some tk colors are ')
text.insert('insert', 'red', 'RED')
text.insert('insert', ' and ')
text.insert('insert', 'blue', 'BLUE')
text.insert('insert', '.')
root.update()
```

It is possible to add tags after text in inserted and to change a tag configuration after it is used.